# How to Split Column Data Based on Identifier

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I am using oracle database.
I am having data in this format in my column 1234~2345~3456~4567.

I need a query to split the data in the column based on the identifier '~',so that i can pick out the value after the second occurrence of the identifier.
May i know who can i achieve this.

Comment: Take a look at https://blogs.oracle.com/aramamoo/entry/how_to_split_comma_separated_string_and_pass_to_in_clause_of_select_statement

Comment: From PL/SQL you can use the `apex_util.string_to_table` function

Comment: Do you just need to pick the second value? Then you can use `INSTR` and `SUBSTR`. But if you need to split it in columns or rows than this is a different story, can you clarify?

Comment: @hol The idea is to have a query to pull out say 3 and 4 values too .. and extend it as well

Comment: @Mahiz Then PL Audet pointed you to the solution. Do you need any more help with it?

Comment: @hol The solution was good. Thank you.

Comment: @hol I think there is a better way to inform the new user how SO works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at 
https://blogs.oracle.com/aramamoo/entry/how_to_split_comma_separated_string_and_pass_to_in_clause_of_select_statement

Comment: Well as you did know that I don't want to post an own answer but out of curiosity because I never had that problem I did an SQL to test it which might helps others: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fd870/15 `select distinct id,level,regexp_substr(tokens,'[^~]+', 1, level) from mytable connect by regexp_substr(tokens, '[^~]+', 1, level) is not null order by 1,2`